# What's a good way to track custom workouts using smartbands or smartwatches?

Tags: exercise, tracking, app

community. This is my first post here. I would like to start tracking my workouts, and wondered about which devices I could get. What I want is:

- Plank exercise log (time based)
- Log rest times between exercises
- Lifting exercises log (reps based)

I would like to create custom routines like:

**Workout A**

- Plank (01:30)
- Rest (00:30)
- Bench press (01:30)
- Rest (00:30)

3 series of that workout

My question: what option(s) would I have to look in a smart band or smartwatch to accomplish what I want ? A HIIT timer, interval timer ?

Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: This sort of recommendation question isn’t a great fit for our site.